# Redirecting STDOUT of a pipe in Perl

Tags: perl, pipe, io-redirection

I feel as though there should be a simple way to do this, but searching around gives me no good leads. I just want to `open()` a pipe to an application, write some data to it, and have the output of the subprocess sent to the `STDOUT` of the calling script.

```
open(my $foo, '|-', '/path/to/foo');
print $foo 'input'; # Should behave equivalently to "print 'output'"
close($foo);
```

Is there a simple way to do this, or have I hit upon one of the many "can't get there from here" moments in Perl?

Comment: Does your process output to screen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The subprocess will inherit STDOUT automatically.  This works for me:

```
open(my $f, "|-", "cat");
print $f "hi\n";
```

If you are not really closing the pipe immediately the problem might be on the other end:  STDOUT is line-buffered by default, so you see `print "hello world\n"` immediately.  The pipe to your subprocess will be block-buffered by default, so you may actually be waiting for the data from your perl script to reach the other program:

```
open(my $f, "|-", "cat");
print $f "hi\n";
sleep(10);
close($f); # or exit
# now output appears
```

Try adding `select $f; $| = 1` (or I think the more modern way is `$f->autoflush(1)`)

Comment: Huh. Must be a problem with the particular application, then.

Comment: Added another idea -- not sure if edits show up as notifications for you.

Comment: It doesn’t do any good to sleep after the print down a pipe: even perlio uses stdio-style pipe buffering. `select((select($f),$|=1)[0])` fixes that. Hm, is there some reason for such an exotic pipe open yet without error checking? Why not just: `open(my $f, "|cat") || die "can't open pipe to cat: $!";`?

Comment: @tchrist: Agree some error handling is a good idea, perhaps the original problem is that the open fails?  Not sure what you mean about sleep:  I was just illustrating how expectations of line-buffering (stdio auto flush on newline) are broken if you open your own pipe or file and get block-buffering by default.

Comment: anybody who thinks stdio line buffers is too used to output to terminals instead of to pipes, sockets, or files.